# Finding User object where object in hasMany relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a User object, and in that user I define the following relationship:

```
public function car()
{
   return $this->hasMany('Car');
}
```

Now if I want to find a User with a Ford, how can I accomplish something like this?

```
$user = User::where('car.make', 'ford')->first();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use [`whereHas`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations):

```
$user = User::whereHas('car', function($query) {
    $query->where('make', 'ford');
})->first();
```

BTW, since this is a has-many relationship, you should probably rename the relationship to `cars`.